# Pass the value of checkbox via ajax, php, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day. guys i got a problem.
I need to send my checkbox value via ajax to a php file

**My question**
i want to pass the value in both cases whenever it is check or not.
if it is checked then it should have pass the `value="true"` 
and if it is not check then simply the value in content should be passed. via ajax jquery

**Note**

i know code in jquery (AJAX) file should be updated with `if condition` but i don't know how to do it

**Update** **-----**

I have fix the issue of check conditon by following answers

**but**

in wallajax.php file when i use  `if(isset($_POST["content"]))`
then i am getting te value of content via ajax and it is also returing its value in page

but when i am using  `if(isset($_POST["content"]) && isset($_POST["check"])  )` 
no value is retrieved as a result no return value showing on page

i cant understand, where is the problem happeing, is it on ajax script or wallajax.php file

my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#px").click(function() {
    var status2 = $("#status2").val();
     var checkit= $("#checkit").is(':checked');
       var dataString = 'content=' + status2 + '&check=' + checkit;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wallajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resol) {
        $('#wallposts').prepend(resol);
        console.log(resol)
              }
        }); return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

wallajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST["content"]) && isset($_POST["check"])  ) 
{
---fetched value------feed value in databse------
 }
```

index.php

```
<textarea name="content" id="status2"></textarea>
<input name="check" id="checkit" type="checkbox" value="true">check it</input>
<div id="px">Post</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#checkit").val();
```

use

```
$("#checkit").prop('checked');
```

OR

```
$("#checkit").is(':checked');
```

---

I would suggest

```
var data = {'content': status2, 'check': checkit};
```

instead of

```
var dataString = 'content=' + status2 + '&check=' + checkit;
```

Comment: thank you, 
can you lookout for wallajax.php page because in console value is passed but i think is not retriving in wallajax.php

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues, your dataString does not include a "&" between variables and the checkbox value is not being captured correctly, below fixes both issues:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#px").click(function() {
    var status2 = $("#status2").val();
     var checkit= $("#checkit").prop('checked');
       var dataString = 'content=' + status2 + '&check=' + checkit;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wallajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resol) {
        $('#wallposts').prepend(resol);
        console.log(resol)
              }
        }); return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

There is also an issue with your php, you are explicitly "setting" the variables when you prepare the dataString in this way, so

```
isset($_POST['check']) && isset($_POST['content'])
```

will always return true, a better way to get the data so that doesnt happen is to use jquery's .serialize() method on the form, although i dont see the form element in your html i assume there is one

```
var dataString = $('yourForm').serialize();
```